# Choose specfic Activity from Android Activity stack

Tags: java, android, dynamic, stack, stack-trace

[Here's](http://hostmypicture.com/images/capturiti.png) My Running Activity Stack
Now I Want to choose A specific Activity from the multiple running Instance of same activity 
Like I have a activity displaymessage Which I am creating according to this logic

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {


            String temp = userlist.get(position).getId();
            int flag = 1;
            Intent i = new Intent();

             for (String s : recent_id){
                if (s.equals(temp)){
                    flag = 0 ;
                    break;
                }

             }
             if(flag == 1)
                recent_id.add(userlist.get(position).getId());

             else if(flag == 0)
               i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);


             i.setClass(DisplayUser.this, MessageActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));
             i.putExtra("icon", userlist.get(position).getIcon());
             i.putExtra("name", userlist.get(position).getName());
             startActivity(i);

        }


    });
```

I want to attach some id to my displaymessage activity so whenever it's new instance is launched a id is attached to it and i can retrieve from activity stack easily .. can i do it that way or I am completely wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand what activity life cycle is.

According to your requirement [try this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result) this might help you.

You can call which activity you want according specific result you had mentioned to your activity using `startActivityForResult()` method.